# mvc bundling adds text to bootstrap.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I have an MVC project that includes bootstrap 3.0.0. On my dev machine everything works fine. But on the test server something goes amiss. I think this has to do with bundling.

Dev machine:

```
Url of page: localhost/MvcProject/page  
Bootstrap.js line 1639: var $href = /^#\w/.test(href) && $(href)
```

Test environment:

```
Url of page website.com/blabla/MvcProject/page  
Bootstrap.js line 1639: var $href = /blabla/^#\w/.test(href) && $(href)
```

The boostrap.js does not get changed on my dev machine, but is on the test environment. It thinks `/^#\w/.test(href)` is a url and adjusts it for the "new" relative url.

Can I tell the bundling not to adjust this JavaScript file? Or do you see another way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found it. It's not in our system.

Apparently when the admins for the test environment publish something, they alter all URL's in the files. In all files. Even script or code files. They're turning it off.

After a lot of meetings with those idi... admins, one of them finally remembered that they did that. Part of their automated process. Good thing they know their own processes so well.

/facepalm